# How do I get testnet block height?

Tags: blockchain, testnet, height

Like I would do `wget -O - http://blockchain.info/q/getblockcount 2>/dev/null` for the main net.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Blockchain.info does not track the testnet, but blockexplorer.com does. In fact the API you're using was originally from blockexplorer.com, and blockchain.info simply adopted it.

```
wget -O - http://blockexplorer.com/testnet/q/getblockcount 2> /dev/null
```

or shorter

```
curl http://blockexplorer.com/testnet/q/getblockcount
```

Comment: this doesn't work anymore :( gives a 502...

Answer (score 0):

BlockExplorer doesn't work anymore for me (redirecting to testnet.blockexplorer.com which throws a 502) so I found a new alternative:

http://tbtc.blockr.io/api/v1/coin/info

You have to get the "last_block" element.

(For mainnet: http://btc.blockr.io/api/v1/coin/info)